# Wild card subdomain not working [This site can’t be reached] .Works fine for few minute when running network-manager restart

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost

etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.test
  ServerAlias *.mysite.test
  ServerAdmin mysite@adf.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public
  <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enable/mysite.test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.test
  ServerAlias *.mysite.test
  ServerAdmin yurstore@adf.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public
  <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

//etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

// /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   sanjay-Inspiron-3542
127.0.0.1   mysite.test
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

etc/dnsmasq.d/test

```
address=/test/127.0.0.1
```

// /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
#address=/test/127.0.0.1
#server=/test/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

laravel /public/.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
```

When running 
$sudo service NetworkManager restart 
works fine for few minutes

Comment: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

#dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no